# Ubuntu 17.10 VirtualBox File, etc. menus don't work

Tags: virtualbox, 17.10, menu

I've been running VirtualBox on Ubuntu for years. I just upgraded to 17.10 with a clean install. I installed VirtualBox from the Software Center and then removed and reinstalled it using apt.

The application starts up normally, but the File, Machine, and Help menus only turn blue when I click on them, they don't drop down. The New toolbar works correctly.

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10 now defaults sessions to using [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(display_server_protocol)) instead of Xorg. As there are known issues with running VirtualBox with Wayland, you might want to try logging into your session under Xorg and then test your VirtualBox install again.

Comment: Thanks for the response. For no apparent reason, VirtualBox menu suddenly started working. I assume I downloaded an update, but I didn't take any particular action.

Comment: Glad to hear. If your issue has been resolved, or is no longer valid, please delete or mark as answered (you can answer your own question).

Comment: I was able to partially solve this on Ubuntu 18.04 by dragging my VirtualBox window onto a secondary monitor. Granted, this will only work if you have a second monitor!